# I am getting error at my cellForRowAtIndexPath in tableview after i filter with predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

[__NSDictionaryM safeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005e060

[__NSDictionaryM safeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005e060 [IssuesViewController-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

Assertion failure in -[STCollapseTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:8174

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 115}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 115}>)'
*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d8bb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001087c3141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d8fcf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x000000010835d3b6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x0000000109aeefcf -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 230
5   UIKit                               0x0000000109afa7b8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 836
6   UIKit                               0x0000000109afa9a8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
7   UIKit                               0x0000000109acf2e9 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2845
8   UIKit                               0x0000000109b0397c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 111
9   UIKit                               0x0000000109aeab2a -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 233
10  UIKit                               0x0000000109a5120b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107905904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001078f9526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001078f93a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107888e92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001078b5130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
16  UIKit                               0x0000000109987307 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
17  UIKit                               0x000000010a187cab __handleEventQueue + 5843
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d31c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d170cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d165ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d16016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b8eaa24 GSEventRunModal + 62
23  UIKit                               0x000000010998e0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
24  comress                             0x000000010626910f main + 111
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b4d765d start + 1)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

This is sample code:

```
 NSArray *postDupe = [[_postsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.@allValues"] valueForKeyPath:@"post"];

 NSArray *foundArray = nil;

 predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"post_id.stringValue contains [c] %@",@"18586"];

 foundArray = [postDupe filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

 long foundIndex = 0;
        long count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<foundArray.count; i++)
        {
            foundIndex = [postDupe indexOfObject: [foundArray objectAtIndex: i]];
            //NSLog(@"%@ is at index %d", string, index);
            }
        _filterPostsArray = [_postsArray objectAtIndex:foundIndex];


        }
    searchActive = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [_issuesTable reloadData];
    });
```

Sample Json Data:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x608000449a80>(
    {

        14556 =     {
            newCommentsCount = 0;
            post =         {
                "post_id" = 18609;
                seen = 1;
                status = 0;
                statusWasUpdated = 0;
               "updated_on" = "1506061049.023";
           };
       };
   },
)
```

Comment: The data you show is a *dictionary*, it has a key `14556` which is also dictionary valued, that nested dictionary has a key `post` which is also dictionary valued, and finally that dictionary has the key `post_id`. What is actually in your `_postsArray`? The final inner dictionary or something else?

Comment: @CRD this is part of it, i have other set of data like 14557 or etc. The array contains all the dict values

Comment: @CRD, so anyway to get the value.

Comment: Try typing something like `[nspredicate] nested dictionary` into SO's search box and see if any of the many questions on nested dictionaries help you.

Comment: If you don't use CoreData, I'd recommend to use a `predicateWithBlock:`: `NSDictionary *subDict = [obj[allValues] firstObject]; `return [subDict[@"post"] isEqualToString:@"myPostID18609"];` (if it's a string, if it's a `NSNumber`, use a `NSNumber` to compare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [__NSDictionaryM safeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Looks like you have a dictionary and are treating it like an array.

Run your code in the debugger and examine the values of the variables as you move through your algorithm, this should show you where you go wrong.

**Guessing:**

1. The key path in your predicate `post_id.stringValue` should be `post.post_id.stringValue` - your dictionary contains a key `post` whose value is itself a dictionary which has a key `post_id`.
2. `_filterPostsArray = [_postsArray objectAtIndex:foundIndex]` sounds like it is assigning a dictionary to an array. You probably wanted this statement to be in the loop and *adding* the dictionary as a new element to the array?

HTH